# How is text indented and glued within TikZ node contents?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw=red,very thin, align=left,every node/.style={draw,rectangle}]
\node (unaligned) {
\ttfamily
parameters: a\\
\phantom{parameters:} b};

\node[node font=\ttfamily, right=of unaligned] {
parameters: a\\
\phantom{parameters:} b};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: render]

The difference is obvious, a and b are not aligned in the first node. Apparently, the `\phantom{...}` is not typeset using the `\ttfamily`, hence it's size is different. I could have used the incantation `font=\ttfamily`, which would work just as fine as `node font=\ttfamily`.

The PGF manual only mentions this a bit vaguely:

> Naturally, you can just use a font command like \small or \rm at the
>   beginning of a node. However, the following two options make it easier
>   to set the font used in nodes on a general basis.

and

> The keyword node is typically followed by some options and then some
>   text between curly braces. This text is put inside a normal TEX box
>   (if the node specification directly follows a coordinate, which is
>   usually the case, TikZ is able to perform some magic so that it is
>   even possible to use verbatim text inside the boxes)

Apparently I cannot "just use a font command". Why? Is this connected to the aforementioned "magic" in any way? Also, what is a "normal TeX box"? I am aware of `\parbox`, `\mbox` and `\minipage`, and they all behave a little bit differently with respect to indentation and similar things.

Comment: To my knowledge this is one of the main reasons why one should use `font` or `node font`. (The first scenario can also be achieved with `\node[execute at begin node=\ttfamily,...`.)

Answer (score 1):

That's because if you omit `text width` Ti*k*Z will try to figure out the text width for you by splitting lines at `\\` and packing them into an `\halign`.  That is also documented under [`/tikz/align`](http://mirror.aut.ac.nz/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#pgfmanual-pos-160) in the PGF manual.

Essentially these two are equivalent:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent \tikz \node[align=left,inner sep=0pt] {
  \ttfamily parameters: a\\
  \phantom{parameters:} b
};

\noindent \halign{#\hfil\cr
  \hbox{\ttfamily parameters: a}\cr
  \hbox{\phantom{parameters:} b}\cr
}
\end{document}
```

[image]